# saveFileDialog.FileName - How can I swap * for X? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Theres a textbox that says ' how to * ' ( myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text ) if i click SAVE. A dialog window pops up and the save file name is ' how to * ' but i want the save file name to be ' how to X '

---

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text) ?
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to take the string that a user enters and replace all '*' characters with an 'X' character?

Comment: Yes when a user enters a string in the txtResearch textbox. It will have an asterisk *. that string is the default save filename. I simply want to replace the asterisk IN the save dialog to X

Comment: Can not understan your question clearly.

Comment: Lookup the string.Replace Method..

Comment: When you say "It will have an asterisk *. that string is the default save filename" it's confusing.  It won't necessarily have anything, it will have whatever the user decides to type into the box.  You set the default value before you show the dialog, and then after the dialog closes the final value of the FileName is whatever the user decided it would be.

Comment: sorry for being so confusing. englsh is not my natural language . let me try again

Comment: theres a textbox that says ' how to * '   ( myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text )

if i click SAVE. a dialog window pops up and the save file name is ' how to * '

when i click save i want the dialog window to pop up and the save file name to be 

' how to X '

Comment: Sounds like a strange request, why out curiosity do you want to do this?

Comment: because when i click save the text file doesn't save because of the asterisk

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
// use this namespace`
    using System.Windows.Forms;

 // write this code
SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
s.FileName= myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text.Replace("*", "X");
```

Comment: hi there, i get an error that says the type or namespace name 'savefiledialog' could not be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That's because for some reason he's constructing a new one, you'll want to use this against the save file dialog you already have.

Comment: use using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: He's using WPF.  He should be using the Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog instead.  Do not add a reference to System.Windows.Forms for this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really understand your question but will take a wild guess and say that this is what you need:

```
string fileName = myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text.Replace("*", "X");
saveFileDialog.FileName = fileName;
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

This will ensure that the default filename doesn't contain any asterix. However, it won't prevent your user from putting his own in inside the dialog box...

Comment: sorry for being so confusing. let me try to explain it better

Comment: theres a textbox that says ' how to * '   ( myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text )

if i click SAVE. a dialog window pops up and the save file name is ' how to * '

when i click save i want the dialog window to pop up and the save file name to be 

' how to X '

Comment: You can set the default save file name before you show the dialog via `saveFileDiaglog.FileName = "your string here";` this is what will show up in the dialog box. You could replace any instances of `*` with the code above before your call to `ShowDialog()`, this would ensure that all * are automatically replaced with an X. But im still unsure if this is what you want?

Comment: Ok, then you'll want to use `Replace()` on the textbox. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: does not seem to be working. I don't get any errors but the filename is still including the asterisk

Comment: If i understand what you want, it works fine. I ran a little mockup and used: `string fileName = textBox1.Text.Replace("*", "X");
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 1):

```
saveFileDialog1.FileName = myResearchPage.txtResearch.Text.Replace("*", "X");
```

Assuming your saveFileDialog box is named "saveFileDialog1" this will work as you want it to.

This is assuming you have added a savefiledialog box to your windows form already, which is a simple drag and drop. It will not show, but it will be bound and have the name at the bottom of the GUI builder in visual studio express.